# Project ERROR: Could not find feature when running qmake on any qt module

Tags: qt, qt5, raspberry-pi3

i am following guide written in here: https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS
everythng runs smooth (needed to add fonts) - I can run and debug an application on my device from my pc.

But if I try to install any module (qtdeclarative, qt3d, qtquickcontrols, qtquickcontrols2) it just tells me no for a lack of some feature. 
For examplee:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtdeclarative.git -b 5.9.0
cd qtdeclarative
~/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake -r
```

Gives me lots of positive code, but ends with:

```
Reading /path/to/raspi/qtdeclarative/src/quick/quick.pro
Project ERROR: Could not find feature qml-network.
```

Similar thing applies for the rest.

Could anyone tell me what to do?
edit
to make it worse same thing happens on 5.9.2 but 5.7 isn't compatible with rpi3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do

```
~/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake
```

without the `-r` option. It worked for me.